# Why do `jobs` and `dirs` run in command subsitution, process substitution, pipeline, and background jobs output the same as in original shell?

Tags: bash

If I am correct, command substitution, process substitution, pipeline, and background jobs run the commands specified within themselves in a subshell not in the original shell.

But when the commands are `jobs` or `dirs`, they output exactly the same as when they are run directly in the original shell:

```
echo $( jobs )

cat <(jobs)

jobs | less

echo $( dirs )

cat <(dirs)

dirs | less

dirs &
```

Why is that? Is it because the subshells inherit the jobs and dirs stack from the original shell, or because `jobs` and `dirs` are run in the original shell instead of the subshells?

But

```
jobs &
```

doesn't output anything. Why is it different from the other commands? Thanks.

Related [Does sourcing a script in subshells still allow the commands in the script to access the state of the original shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458988/does-sourcing-a-script-in-subshells-still-allow-the-commands-in-the-script-to-ac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of this answer is that `jobs` and `dirs` are built-ins, so typically bash will just run those directly instead of invoking a subshell.

That's true for the cases where there are pipes or command substitution (`$(jobs)`) or process substitution (`<(jobs)`).

That's not really the case for running the command in background (`jobs &`) or requesting a subshell explicitly (with `( jobs )`.)

So that explains the last part of your question. When you run `jobs` in a subshell, it's indeed showing the jobs for the subshell itself.

Here's a good demonstration of this concept:

```
$ sleep 1001 &
[1] 15927
$ sleep 1002 &
[2] 15940
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 1001 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 1002 &
$ ( sleep 1003 & jobs )
[1]+  Running                 sleep 1003 &
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 1001 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 1002 &
```

You'll see that the case where `jobs` is running in a subshell, only the jobs of that subshell (in this case `sleep 1003`) will be displayed.

Now, to wrap up, we need to address the middle part of the question, which is why `dirs &` (which does indeed run in a subshell, as would `( dirs )`) will still show the directories saved in the pushd stack.

It turns out that this is because the shell exports the list of directories in the special array variable `DIRSTACK`, which is then inherited by subshells. (You can read more about `DIRSTACK` [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-COPROC).)

One way to demonstrate how this works is to use `pushd` on the subshell and see how that doesn't affect the directory stack of the original shell:

```
$ dirs
~
$ pushd ~/tmp
~/tmp ~
$ ( dirs; pushd / >/dev/null; dirs )
~/tmp ~
/ ~/tmp ~
$ dirs
~/tmp ~
```

I believe that should address all the items you asked about.

---

**UPDATE**: bash has a special provision to make `jobs | less` work, having the `jobs` command run in the current shell (which is not the case for other built-ins.)

The code has a check that is stored in a `jobs_hack` variable, which is later checked to make it run without creating a sub-shell and allow piping the output of `jobs` to another command.

See [here](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=bash.git;a=blob;f=execute_cmd.c;h=2a3df6d620eb3ce6d645bbd717d456c5daf8bf29;hb=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#l4901) for the relevant part of the source code that implements this. (As of bash 4.4)

Comment: where do you get the basis for your initial argument? in my experience `bash` is particularly notorious for needless childing... i would assume `$!` is a major factor here, and maybe a sloppy handover/lazy check where `$$` remains unaltered. too lazy to check now, though.

Comment: Thanks. "the shell exports the list of directories in the special array variable DIRSTACK", but `env` doesn't show `DIRSTACK`

Comment: Do you find any general rule about which other builtin commands  used  in either of the five cases  are run in subshells  or in original shells?

Comment: In `cd .. | pwd`, `cd ..` runs in a subshell not in the original shell. Why is it different from `jobs | cat`?

Comment: Hi @Tim, I updated the answer to address that. Indeed, there's a special case for `jobs`, bash will recognize it and force it to run in the current shell process, exactly in order to support this use case, of piping its output to another command. I hope that helps!