# Does sourcing a script in subshells still allow the commands in the script to access the state of the original shell?

Tags: bash

I have a script, which access some state of a shell

```
$ cat my.sh 
#! /bin/bash
jobs
dirs
```

The state of a bash shell is:

```
$ dirs 
/tmp/test/tt ~/program_files 

$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
```

I run sourcing the script in subshells of process substitution, command expansion, pipeline and background.  Since they are run in subshells not in the original shell, I expect them not to output anything.

But in  process substitution and command expansion, why do both `jobs` and `dirs` output the same as if they were run in the original shell?

```
$ cat <( source ./my.sh )
[1]+  Running                 sleep 100 &
/tmp/test/tt ~/program_files 

$ echo $(source ./my.sh)
[1]+ Running sleep 100 & /tmp/test/tt ~/program_files
```

But in  pipeline and background, why does only `dirs` output the same as if it were run in the original shell, while   `jobs` doesn't?

```
$ source ./my.sh | cat
/tmp/test/tt ~/program_files 

$ source ./my.sh &
[2] 32229
/tmp/test/tt ~/program_files 
[2]+  Done                    source ./my.sh
```

Thanks.

Related [Why do `jobs` and `dirs` run in command subsitution, process substitution, pipeline, and background jobs output the same as in original shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458984/why-do-jobs-and-dirs-run-in-command-subsitution-process-substitution-pipel)

Comment: See my answer in the other question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/458991/281844. We should really mark them as duplicates.

Comment: i think it has to do with the order of redirections and the value of `$-`. all pipelines must run in their own process group when run from a job-controlled `-m` shell, but not from a subshell of one such. `<` and `$()` examples are of simple commands, not pipelines, and so probably dont graduate to separate process groups - though im a little rusty on the subject material. good question, though

Comment: Hmm... `jobs | cat` does print a background process, but `echo jobs > jobs.sh; . ./jobs.sh |cat` doesn't...